# Defining an aggregation function with groupby in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, aggregation

I would like to collapse my dataset using `groupby` and `agg`, however after collapsing, I want the new column to show a string value only for the grouped rows.
For example, the initial data is:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([["a",1],["a",2],["b",2]], columns=['category','value'])

    category    value
0      a         1
1      a         3
2      b         2
```

Desired output:

```
   category   value
0     a      grouped
1     b         2
```

How should I modify my code (to show "grouped" instead of 3):

```
df=df.groupby(['category'], as_index=False).agg({'value':'max'})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a lambda with a ternary:

```py
df.groupby("category", as_index=False)
    .agg({"value": lambda x: "grouped" if len(x) > 1 else x})
```

This outputs:

```py
  category    value
0        a  grouped
1        b        2
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution:

```
(df.assign(value = np.where(
    df.duplicated(subset=['category'], keep=False), 'grouped', df['value']))
 .drop_duplicates())
```

Output:

```
  category    value
0        a  grouped
2        b        2
```